# Twisted forms with real points of a real Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $X={\rm Gr}_{n,k,{\Bbb R}}$ denote the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces in ${\Bbb R}^n$.
We regard $X$ as an ${\Bbb R}$-variety with the set of complex points $X({\Bbb C})={\rm Gr}_{n,k,{\Bbb C}}$.
We consider the twisted $\Bbb R$-forms  $_c X$  of $X$ where $c\in {\rm Aut\,} X_{\Bbb C}$ is a $1$-cocycle.
They have the following property: $({}_c X)\times_{\Bbb R}{\Bbb C}\simeq X\times_{\Bbb R}{\Bbb C}$.

> **Question 1.** What are the twisted $\Bbb R$-forms $_c X$  of $X$ having ${\Bbb R}$-points?

> **Question 2.** What are references for the version of Question 1
> over an arbitrary field rather than over ${\Bbb R}$?

Concerning Question 1, I have found the following twisted forms $_c X$,
for which I write the set of ${\Bbb R}$-points $({}_c X)({\Bbb R})$.

1. ${\rm Gr}_{n,k,{\Bbb R}}.$
2. For $n=2n',\ k=2k'$, the quaternionic Grassmannian ${\rm Gr}_{n',k',{\Bbb H}}$
   of $k'$-dimensional subspaces in ${\Bbb H}^{n'}$,
   where ${\Bbb H}$ denotes the division algebra of Hamilton's quaternions.
3. For $n=2k$, the isotropic Hermitian Grassmannian whose ${\Bbb R}$-points are
   the $k$-dimensional subspaces $W\subset{\Bbb C}^n={\Bbb C}^{2k}$ that are totally isotropic
   with respect to the Hermitian form $\mathcal H$ with matrix
   ${\rm diag}(-1,\dots,-1,+1,\dots, +1)$ where $-1$ appears $k$ times
   and also $+1$ appears $k$ times.
   Here a subspace $W\subset {\Bbb C}^{2k}$ is called totally isotropic
   if the restriction of $\mathcal H$ to $W$ is zero.

> **Question 3.** Do these exhaust all twisted real forms of $X$ having real points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Let $G:={\rm Aut}(X)^0$. Then it is well-known that
$$G_{\mathbb C}= ({\rm Aut}(X)^0)_{\mathbb C}= ({\rm Aut}(X)_{\mathbb C})^0= {\rm Aut}(X_{\mathbb C})^0\cong {\rm PGL}(n,\mathbb C).$$ So $G$ is a real form of ${\rm PGL}(n,\mathbb C)$ which means that $G$ is isomorphic to ${\rm PGL}(n,\mathbb R)$, ${\rm PGL}(n/2,\mathbb H)$, or ${\rm PU}(p,n-p)$. On the other hand, $X$ has a real point $x$ which means $X\cong G/P$ with $P=G_x$. It follows from $G_{\mathbb C}/P_{\mathbb C}\cong X_{\mathbb C}\cong {\rm Gr}_{n,k,\mathbb C}$ that $P_{\mathbb C}$ is a maximal parabolic which is defined over $\mathbb R$. Looking at the Satake diagram of $G$ it corresponds therefore to a non-compact self-conjugate simple root $\alpha_k$. This gives the following possibilities
$$
 G={\rm PGL}(n,\mathbb R), k=1,\ldots,n-1\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{your first case}
$$
$$
G={\rm PGL}(n/2,\mathbb H), k=2,4\ldots,n-2\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{your second case}
$$
$$
G={\rm PU}(p,n-p), k=p=n/2\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{your third case}
$$
This argument should generalize to arbitrary fields. The first two cases combine to $X=$ space of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $D^n$ where $D$ is a central simple algebra.

Comment: Dear Friedrich, many thanks! However, it is not quite correct that ${\rm Aut}(X_{\Bbb C})\cong {\rm PGL}(n,{\Bbb C})$.  When $n=2k$, the connected group $ {\rm PGL}(n,{\Bbb C})$ is a subgroup of index 2 in ${\rm Aut}(X_{\Bbb C})$.

Comment: The other connected component of the automorphism group contains the following automorphism: $\phi_B\colon W\mapsto W^{\bot B}$. Here $W$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $V={\Bbb C}^n$, and $W^{\bot B}$ is the annihilator of $W$ in $V$ with respect to a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $B$ on $V$. For example, we can take the form $B=B_0$ with matrix $I_n={\rm diag}(1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: If instead of $B_0$ we choose the symmetric bilinear form $B_1$ with matrix ${\rm diag}(-1,\dots,-1,+1,\dots, +1)$ where $-1$ appears $k$ times 
and also $+1$ appears $k$ times, then, I think, $\phi_{B_1}$ is a cocycle giving my third case.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked the graph automorphism when $n=2k$. But still, if one defines $G:={\rm Aut}(X)^0$ then the argument should go through because of $G_{\mathbb C}=({\rm Aut}(X)^0)_{\mathbb C}=({\rm Aut}(X)_{\mathbb C})^0={\rm PGL}(n,\mathbb C)$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $K$ of characteristic zero such that
$$
X_{\bar{K}} \cong \mathrm{Gr}(k,n)_{\bar{K}}
$$
and $X(K) \ne \varnothing$.

First, consider the case $n \ne 2k$. Let $r = \gcd(k,n)$. Then there is an $r$-torsion Brauer class $\beta \in \mathrm{Br}(K)$ representable by a Severi--Brauer variety of dimension $k - 1$ and a Severi--Brauer variety $Y$ of dimension $n - 1$ with class $\beta$ such that
$$
X \cong \mathrm{Hilb}_{\mathrm{P}^{k-1}}(Y)
$$
is the component of the Hilbert scheme that parameterizes subschemes with the same Hilbert polynomial as $\mathrm{P}^{k-1}$. Let us call such $X$ a **Severi--Brauer Grassmannian** of class $\beta$.

Now consider the case $n = 2k$. Then either $X$ is a Severi--Brauer Grassmannian as before, or there is a quadratic extension $K'/K$ such that $X_{K'}$ is a Severi--Brauer Grassmannian.

Comment: Dear Sasha, I do believe that the Severi-Brauer Grassmannian of class $\beta$ has a $K$-point. However, I don't believe that any variety $X$ over $K$ such that $X_{K'}$ is a Severi-Brauer Grassmannian, has a $K$-point. Could you please comment?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: you are absolutely right, I forgot the condition that $\beta$ should be the class of a Severi--Brauer variety of dimension $k - 1$. I added the assumption to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I meant the case $n=2k\,$.  I don't believe that any variety $X$ over $K$
such that there is a quadratic extension $K'/K$ for which $X_{K'}$ is a Severi-Brauer Grassmannian, has a $K$-point. Here you probably have to mention a Hermitian form of maximal possible index....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Yes, right, the existence of a $K$-point in this case may be tricky. But it is quite plausible that it can be phrased in terms of a Hermitian form; I will think about that.